# wrong rules ANTLR

Tags: antlr, grammar

sorry for my english. Learning rules antlr, I turned the curve calculator, please tell me where I can not properly written.

- > If I write: **2+(2*2)** my calculator displays: 4.
- >If I write: **2+pi** my calculator displays: line 1:2 no viable alternative at input 'pi' line
   1:4 no viable alternative at input ''4.0
- > If I write: **cos 2** my calculator displays: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'cos'
   0.9092974268256817

And the same type of errors ...I ask your help

Here's what I got:

```
grammar rulle;

options {
  language = Java;
}

rule returns [double value]
    : exp=additionExp { $value = $exp.value; }
    ; 

additionExp returns [double value]
    :    m1=involutExp      {$value = $m1.value;}
         ( '+' m2=involutExp  {$value += $m1.value;}
         | '-' m2=involutExp  {$value -= $m2.value;}
         )* 
    ; 

involutExp returns [double value]
    : i1=radicalExp {$value = $i1.value;} 
        ( '^' i1=radicalExp {$value = Math.pow($value, $i1.value);}
        )*
    ;

radicalExp returns [double value]
    : r1=matchSinCosExp {$value = $r1.value;}
        ( '!' r1=matchSinCosExp{$value = Math.pow($value, 1.0/$r1.value);}
        )*
    ;

matchSinCosExp returns [double value]
    : m1=piExp {$value = $m1.value;}
        ('sin' m1=piExp {$value = Math.sin($m1.value);}
        |'cos' m1=piExp {$value = Math.sin($m1.value);}
        )*
    ;

piExp returns [double value]
    : p1=multiplyExp {$value = $p1.value;}
        ('pi' p1=multiplyExp {$value = ($p1.value-$p1.value)+Math.PI;} 
        )*
    ;

multiplyExp returns [double value]
    :    a1=atomExp     {$value = $a1.value;}
         ( '*' a2=atomExp {$value *= $a2.value;}
         | '/' a2=atomExp {$value /= $a2.value;}
         )* 
    ;


atomExp returns [double value]
    :    n=Number           {$value = Double.parseDouble($n.text);}
    |    '(' exp=additionExp ')' {$value = $exp.value;}
    ;

Number
    :    ('0'..'9')+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)?
    ;

WS  
    :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems appear in this rule:

```
piExp returns [double value]
    : p1=multiplyExp {$value = $p1.value;}
        ('pi' p1=multiplyExp {$value = ($p1.value-$p1.value)+Math.PI;} 
        )*
    ;
```

The way this rule is structured, to get the value **π** you need to use an expression like `3pi4`, i.e. `pi` is written as a binary operator instead of a primary expression. The values `3` and `4` are effectively ignored because both are assigned to the label `p1` (as opposed to separate labels `p1` and `p2` like you have in other rules), thus the expression `($p1.value-$p1.value)+Math.PI` simplifies to `(0)+Math.PI` which is just `Math.PI`.

You should correct this in the following way:

1. Remove the rule `piExp`.
2. Replace references to `piExp` in `matchSinCosExp` with references to `multiplyExp`.
3. Create a new rule `primaryExp`:

   ```
   primaryExp returns [double value]
     : Number    {$value = Double.parseDouble($Number.text);}
     | 'pi'      {$value = Math.PI;}
     ;
   ```
4. Alter your `atomExp` rule to reference `primaryExp` instead of just `Number`:

   ```
   atomExp returns [double value]
     : primaryExp              {$value = $primaryExp.value;}
     | '(' exp=additionExp ')' {$value = $exp.value;}
     ;
   ```

Comment: May suggest again, as the logarithm of the result? I write like this:
'log'{$value = Math.log($value);} And I outputs:  -Infinity, I tried to do so Math10.log($value), but to no avail

Comment: I came here to do so:
logExp returns [double value]
 : l1 = atomExp {$value = $l1.value;}
 ( 'log' l2=atomExp{$value=Math.log10($l2.value);}
 )*
 ; it is only now displays this message: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'log'. Can, in principle, do not pay attention to it, and it works well,but would like to know why it displays this message